# Override jQuery plugin methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've taken a stab on creating a jQuery plugin used to delete records.  It will first warn the enduser of the record to be deleted, and then delete the record from the database and remove the row from the page.

The method that removes the row from the page is `complete()`.  Typically, I will need to remove rows from the page one of several ways, or maybe even redirect to another page.  As such, I want to configure the plugin to use one of several of these ways, and if one doesn't exist, then be able to totally override the `complete()` method.

My plan was to have the default `complete()` method just call another function (i.e. `deleteMainRow()`), and upon configuration, I would just change the function to be executed (i.e. `deleteChildRow()`).

When attempting to do so, however, I get an error `TypeError: this.deleteChildRow is not a function`.

How can this be done?

PS.  While not my question and while a response is desired but not expected, I am confused on how to access properties and methods within the plugin.  As seen by my script, I sometimes access them as `this.someProperty` and other times as `settings.someProperty`.  Also, to make things work, I needed to define 'elem' and 'dialog' as a global variable which I am not sure is correct.  Any advise would be appreciated.

Thank you

```
$(function() {

    $("#main_list tbody img.deleteListRecord").deleteRecord({
        serverGetRecord:'getDelete_account',
        serverDeleteRecord:'delete_account',
        getMessage  :function (data) {
            return '<p class="dialog-question">ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS ACCOUNT?</p><h1 class="dialog-name">'+data.name+'</h1><p class="dialog-delete">'+h(data.address)+'</p><p class="dialog-location">'+h(data.location)+'</p>';
        },
        complete:function(){console.log(this);this.deleteChildRow();}
    });

});

(function($){
    //Used to delete records.  Will first warn enduser of the record to be deleted, and then delete the record from the database and remove the row from the page.
    var defaults = {
        //Server accessed using index.php?cid=123&controller=someController&task=someTask
        'url'               :'index.php',
        'cid'               :ayb.component.id,  //Default component ID for given page
        'controller'        :ayb.component.controller, //Default controller ID for given page
        'CSRF'              :ayb.CSRF,//CSRF to send to server for all POSTs
        'serverGetRecord'   :'getRecord', //Server method to get record data
        'serverDeleteRecord':'deleteRecord',//Server method to delete record data
        'getID'             :function () {  //Return ID of record.  User can override if different that this 
            return $(elem).parent().parent().data('id'); 
        },
        'complete'          :function () {  //User can select one of the pre-defined routines or completely override 
            deleteMainRow(); 
        },
        'userComplete'      :function () {},  //Any extra user-defined methods to call when complete 
        'buildMessage'      :function () {  //Create warning message.  Override if user doesn't want to get data from server.
            var t=this;
            $.get(this.url,{cid:this.cid,controller:this.controller,task:this.serverGetRecord,id:this.getID()},function (data){
                dialog.html((data.status==1)?t.getMessage(data):'Error getting delete information.');
                },'json'); 
        },
        'getMessage'        :function (data) {  //Get warning message.  User can override just getMessage and still use buildMessage 
            return '<p class="dialog-question">ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS RECORD?</p>';
        }
    };

    //A couple of pre-defined delete completion routines
    var deleteMainRow=function(){
        $(elem).parent().parent().remove();
    }
    var deleteChildRow=function(){
        alert('deleteChildRow.');
    }
    var dialog; //Should I define this variable here?
    var elem; //Should I define this variable here?

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {});
            dialog=$('<div class="dialog-delete" title=""></div>')
            .appendTo('body')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen    : false,
                resizable   : false,
                height      : 300,
                width       : 440, 
                modal       : true,
                dialogClass : 'hide-title-bar',
                open: function(event, ui){settings.buildMessage()},
                buttons: [{
                    text    : 'YES, DELETE IT',
                    "class" : 'red',
                    click   : function() {
                        dialog.dialog('close');
                        $.post(this.url,{cid:settings.cid,controller:settings.controller,task:settings.serverDeleteRecord,CSRF:settings.CSRF,id:settings.getID()},function (status){
                            if(status==1){
                                settings.complete();
                                settings.userComplete();
                            }
                            else{alert('Error deleting record');}
                        });
                    }
                    },
                    {
                        text     : 'CANCEL',
                        "class"  : 'gray',
                        click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                    }
                ]
            });
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).click(function(e) {
                    elem=this;
                    dialog.dialog('open');
                });
            });
        },
        destroy : function () {
            //Anything else I should do here?
            delete dialog;
            return this.each(function () {});
        }
    };

    $.fn.deleteRecord = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.deleteRecord');
        }    
    };
    }(jQuery)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this:

```
$(function() {

    $("#main_list tbody img.deleteListRecord").deleteRecord({
        serverGetRecord:'getDelete_account',
        serverDeleteRecord:'delete_account',
        getMessage  :function (data) {
            return '<p class="dialog-question">ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS ACCOUNT?</p><h1 class="dialog-name">'+data.name+'</h1><p class="dialog-delete">'+h(data.address)+'</p><p class="dialog-location">'+h(data.location)+'</p>';
        },
        complete:function(){console.log(this);this.deleteChildRow();}
    });

});
```

After your module is declared and called :)

Because you are calling anonymously what wasn't even created yet :)

Comment: Thanks Holybreath.  You mean just load the plugin first, right?  I tried doing so, but no change.  Don't think it makes a difference, but I am loading `<script src="jquery.deleteRecord.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` where main.js has the script you referenced.

Comment: Upon further testing, it does seem to work if I replace `this.deleteChildRow()` with `deleteChildRow()`.  Does the rest of my plugin seem fairly well written?  Thanks again

Comment: I think, this in that context is the this of complete method , not your plugin, be careful with the context :) My personal preference for .each method is .each(function(i, current) {}) , because again , you would want to use less of 'this' everywhere if you're not completely sure of the context, the 'current' is the current element, pretty handy... :)

Comment: Your spot on about needing to be careful about context.  Any recommendations on a good tutorial which will help describe it?

Comment: Here you go , mate : http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score 0):

- Create a closure and save original plugin to future reuse;
- Recreate the plugin with the same name;
- Do all what you want and call original plugin.

  ```
  (function(){
      var originalPlugin = $.fn.pluginname;

      $.fn.pluginname = function(options) {

          var defaults = {
              someOption: 'string',
              anotherOption: { /* some object, if you need it ... */ },
              overridedfunction: function() { /* something */ }
          }

          var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.css('background-color', 'red'); // for example

          /* do something with '$this' applying any jquery */

          originalPlugin.apply(this, arguments);
      }
  })();
  ```